# Android Permission Request Code Issue

Tags: android, android-permissions, phone-call

How to request a Permission? I tried to documentation, but the constant int request code MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE donst seem to just work, anything else to bear in mind for Backwards compatibility?

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getApplicationContext(),
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
```

How to declare MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE constant int?

Comment: Maybe this is will be usefull for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/36787464/3436179

Comment: check this ref: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_phone_calls.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For lower versions you need to declare permission in manifest only,
but for marshmellow you need to give it in the code, where you want to execute the code.

Here, you want to make a call. So, insert/include the code provided below in the code block written to make the call.

```
   public void makeCall(){
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
       intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "123456"));
       int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
       if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
           startActivity(intent);
       } else {
           requestForCallPermission(); 
       }
  }

  private void requestPermission(){
    if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)){} 
    else {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
       }
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
                makeCall(); 
            } 
            break;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yea, i understand that, but how to delcare PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to inform you about it, you need to declare it at top like below private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

Comment: And also change permission in requestPermission() method at else part by CALL_PHONE instead of ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Answer (score 8):

```
public void makeCall(String s)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + s));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        requestForCallPermission();

    } else {
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
public void requestForCallPermission()
{

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE))
    {
    }
    else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                makeCall("100");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

//Now call the method makeCall("your_desire_phone_numder");
makeCall("100");
[Link for more details](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#java)

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "123456"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Try doing this.

Comment: Thanks it started working i guess i put the startActivity in the if before :)

Comment: Yeah that was the only problem. Keep Learning. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it will help you. 
First this will ask you for permission popup after allowing it will call the number.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(HomePanelActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(HomePanelActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(HomePanelActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
            }
        } else {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(HomePanelActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumberToCall));
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(HomePanelActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                    }
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(drawerLayout, "You Deny permission", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I need the Permisson on startup and make the call on button click.
And i NEED the permisson so denying is no option...

Comment: This requiers API23 my app is minSDK 15

Comment: yes you required compile SDK version to 23. Min 15 would work.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify the permission you want to use in the AndroidManifest.xml
like

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```