# Bitmap decode File return null

Tags: android, bitmap

I use intent with action `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to capture image and get a path of the the image. After got the path, I decode it to a bitmap.

```
Bitmap photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath);
```

All work well on **Device1**, the log for image path look like this :

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/QPOS/IMG_20160622_110127_1473532607.jpg
```

Then I run the app to a new device call **Device2**.
The image path I got after capture image:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/QPOS/IMG_20160622_105436_2068195440.jpg
```

It look normal. But the decode method return a null bitmap at this line

```
Bitmap photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath);
```

I do not know why have different between two device, I build on the same source code. 
Can you explain why I got null bitmap for method decode file ? And how to fix this issue ? Thanks.

Update:
I add request permission for API 23 by this method:

```
private void requestPermissions() {
        Log.d("binh", "request Permision");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            List<String> permissionRequestList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionRequestList.add(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
            }

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionRequestList.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionRequestList.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionRequestList.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionRequestList.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
            }

            if (permissionRequestList.size() > 0) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionRequestList.toArray(new String[permissionRequestList.size()]), Constants.REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a code to create path for the image:

```
private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {
        File f = createImageFile();
        currentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        return f;
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
        File albumF = getAlbumDir();
        File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
        return imageF;
    }

    private File getAlbumDir() {
        File storageDir = null;
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            //storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getString(R.string.app_name));
            storageDir = new File(
                    getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getString(R.string.app_name));
            if (storageDir != null) {
                if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                        Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
        }


        return storageDir;
    }
```

After build and granted permission from dialog, I got the same issue.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I read through different topics on SOF and you have exactly the same than me. Every other topic has "similar issue" but at the end their solution does not apply for our issue, not sure why it was flagged as duplicate. Or maybe I missed the good one?

Answer (score 3):

May be your **Device1** 's Android sdk < 23
and **Device2** 's Android sdk == 23 
please check that READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is managed according to Android Sdk 23(at run time required) as well.

Comment: maybe it is the reason, let me check and feed back soon

Comment: private boolean mayRequestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }//if u r in AppcompactActivity try this before create bitmap

Comment: I updated the question, please have a look on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue of alpha channel, so you should use a format for bitmap that preserves alpha:

check below code:

```
  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
  Bitmap photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, options);
```

Comment: list your API levels for both device1 and device2 here pls

Comment: device1 : android 5.1   , device2 (android 6.0)

Comment: ok then you need to set external permission for 6.0

check my this answer for external permission : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253397/android-permisson-request-code-issue/37253779#37253779

Comment: I updated the question.